# Как прописать путь к элементу через xpath для использования в JavascriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Канва: пишу автотест на selenium WebDriver.
Есть Вебэлемент с локатором CSS

```
    @FindBy (css = "#FeedbackMessage")
protected WebElement fm;
```

и есть метод фокусАута этого элемента

```
public void focusout(){
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    js.executeScript("arguments[0].blur();", fm);
```

Вопрос, как добиться того же самого, но с использованием XPath (корректный путь Xpath : //textarea[@id='FeedbackMessage']).

Банальное использование `@FindBy (xpath = "//textarea[@id='FeedbackMessage']")
    protected WebElement fm;` не работает